# Postgres function to validate GTIN

Tags: postgresql, validation

I'm using this function to validate 14 digits GTIN numbers but for some reason I'm not getting what I'm expecting:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION bulk_loader.is_valid_gtin_check_digit(gtin text)
    RETURNS boolean
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    IMMUTABLE STRICT LEAKPROOF
AS $function$
DECLARE
    gtin_length integer;
    check_digit integer;
    gtin_without_check_digit text;
    gtin_reverse text;
    gtin_digits integer[];
    i integer;
    sum integer := 0;
    computed_check_digit integer := 0;
BEGIN
    gtin := regexp_replace(gtin, '\D', '', 'g');
    gtin_length := length(gtin);

    -- If the GTIN code doesn't have 14 digits, return false
    IF gtin_length <> 14 THEN
        RETURN FALSE;
    END IF;

    gtin_without_check_digit := left(gtin, gtin_length - 2);
    check_digit := cast(right(gtin, 1) as integer);

    -- Check if gtin_without_check_digit consists of exactly 13 numeric digits
    IF gtin_without_check_digit ~ '^[0-9]{13}$' THEN
        gtin_reverse := reverse(gtin_without_check_digit);
        gtin_digits := string_to_array(gtin_reverse, NULL)::int[];

        -- Compute the check digit
        FOR i IN 1..array_upper(gtin_digits, 1) LOOP
            sum := sum + gtin_digits[i] * CASE i % 2 WHEN 0 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END;
        END LOOP;
        computed_check_digit := (10 - sum % 10) % 10;

        -- Compare the computed check digit with the last digit of the GTIN code
        RETURN computed_check_digit = check_digit;
    END IF;

    RETURN FALSE;
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RETURN FALSE;
END;
$function$;
```

Then

```
select is_valid_gtin_check_digit('10628176957012');
```

computed_check_digit is 9 while check_digit is 2.
Computed check digit should be 2...

Postgres info:
PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.3.4 [gcc-4_3-branch revision 152973], 64-bit

Comment: According to https://www.gs1.org/services/check-digit-calculator, the check digit should be 9, not 2.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the function is OK and this is an invalid GTIN...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this particular GTIN was invalid therefore the check was failing, the function seems to be OK :=)

I'll leave it here in case someone is looking for ways to validate GTIN

Comment: Actually your function as shown is wrong, but it must differ from the one you were really using.  As it is, the function fails without even computing the check digit, as `gtin_length - 2` should be subtracting 1, not 2.